# String to Enum fails if not written exactly even with ignorecase set to true?

Tags: c#, enums, type-conversion

```
if (user.Access == (UserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserType), str, true))
```

I have a channel bot that takes commands as follow:

```
.add username usertype
```

Now I have to check if the username already have that written access or not but when the usertype is not exactly written as the Enum it always fail.

HeadAdmin written as headadmin for example result in the follow error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Also if I type a non existent enum it will tell me that value X was not found.

How do I convert usertype so it will return true if match and false if not match or not exist ?

Comment: Enum.Parse won't give a NullReferenceException... and I believe the "ignore case" option generally works fine. Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `TryParse` helps with your second problem. No idea with the case sensitive stuff. Can you post code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Show us the code, or we can't help you.

Comment: Are you saying that if you enter `HeadAdmin` it works fine, but if you enter `headadmin` you get a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos i dont have access to .net 4 in this project which is where it seem TryParse exists for enums.

Comment: Your last edit makes it an entirely different question and even more unclear.

Comment: @Henk Holterman yes just ignore my lack of stackoverflowness, the initial question had a mistake of my part where I indeed had the user null in some cases which fixed the first issue, sorry about that. What I want to do now is find a way where I can check if the type exists and after that match if `user.Access == user inputed type` without using try and catch if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example code and the stated error, my first assumption would be that the `user` object is `null`.

Comment: that is true, I have fixed that but what about when the enum is not found ?

Comment: @Guapo `Enum.Parse` will throw an `ArgumentException` in that case (unless it's `str` that's null, then an `ArgumentNullException` will be thrown).